# Javascript / remove hover after click close button

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Help me please!

Show me please how can I remove hover effect after click close button on the right corner?

I can’t figure out how to turn off the effect when you click on the close button

Help me please. I just started to learn javascript, I would like for me to solve this problem, so that I can see how you solved it

I'm insert code snippet!

```js
$(".close_help").click(function() {
  $('.close_help').removeClass(".product__element");
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.product__element').addClass('.product__element')
  }, 100);
});



// // $(".close-hover").click(function () {

// const resetClose = document.querySelector('.close-hover');

// $(".close-hover").click(function () {

//   resetClose.style.display = 'none';
// })

//   //    $('.product__element').removeClass("product__element");
// //    setInterval(function () { $('.product__element').addClass('product__element') }, 500);
// // });
```

```css
.product__element {
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.prodact_sezon {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.4);
}

.close_help {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.interact:hover .close_help {
  display: block;
}


/* .prodact_sezon .product__element:hover {
   transform: scale(02);
} */

.product__element:hover {
  background-color: white;
  transform: scale(1.02);
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 40px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .09);
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.elem123 {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .09);
}

.product__element:hover .elem123 {
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .09);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.product__img {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: -20px;
}

.product__name {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px 5px 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product__name__two {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 5px 7px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: regular;
}

.product__description {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 2px 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: regular;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.product__price {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  /*  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;  */
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #edaf26;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 330;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.product__size {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.product__size-element {
  width: 48%;
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.product__size-element_active {
  border: 3px solid #76AA6F !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.product__add-to-cart-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #76AA6F;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.product__add-to-cart-button:hover {
  background: #63915D;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__element interact">
  <span class="close_help">&times;</span>
  <img alt="Манго Махачонок" class="product__img" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/7iLlgS5o09c">
  <div class="product__name">
    Манго Махачонок
  </div>

  <div class="product__price">
    <span class="product__price-number">220</span> Грн
  </div>
  <div class="elem123">
    <div class="product__size">
      <div class="product__size-element" data-sb-curent-id-or-vendor-code="003" data-sb-curent-price="220" data-sb-curent-size="1 шт.">
        1 шт.
      </div>
      <div class="product__size-element" data-sb-curent-id-or-vendor-code="004" data-sb-curent-price="190" data-sb-curent-size="1 кг">
        1 кг.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product__quantity"></div><button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="003" data-sb-product-img="images/shop/2-min.png" data-sb-product-name="Манго Махачонок" data-sb-product-price="220" data-sb-product-quantity="003" data-sb-product-size="1 шт."><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> В корзину</button>
    <div class="product__description">
      По вкусовым качествам Mango Махачонок идет на первом месте среди всех тайских сортов. У него самая не волокнистая мякоть. Он самый сладкий.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While mentioning the class in any of these functions(addClass() or removeClass()) you do not start it with `.` because these functions are all about classes and you just need to specify them.

**And to turn off the hover, change your jQuery code to**

```
$(".close_help").click(function() {
   $('div').removeClass("product__element");
   setInterval(function() { 
   $('div').addClass('product__element') 
   }, 1000);
});
```

Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/m271gp8L/) of how it works.